# Framework to manage custom tables

Tags: frameworks

In several occasions I have seen people developing a distributed system which allows them to manage customized tables in a similar fashion to excel (spreadsheets).

What I am interested to find is the name of the discipline or the generic tool name for doing this. Additionally, I would like to know any development library (c++, java...) or any framework.

Example:
We have a relational database. This system would allow to the user to compose tables (display) including columns from: any attribute from one entity from the db; foreign attributes; and computed columns.

PS: I am not sure where to place the question. I appreciate any help to move the question to the correct community.

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating a little bit more.
Jasper Reports is a software that can generate this kind of tables as reports.
Hence I assume that the name of the discipline name should be something similar to "**SQL reporting manager**".

Nevertheless, I still interested on libraries to do this at development level (Java, C++, PHP,...)